# How can I remove one of two paths pointing to the same file?

Tags: 22.04

I have these two paths pointing to the same files and none of them being a symlink. If I `rm` one, the other disappears as well (tried on another file with the same symptoms), and I cannot `mv` one into the other. I'm out of ideas

- .config/pgcli/history
- ~/.config/pgcli/history

Some troubleshooting

```
~/dotfiles $ \ls -alL ~/.config/pgcli/history
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lorentz lorentz 3580 jan 25 16:14 /home/lorentz/.config/pgcli/history

~/dotfiles $ \ls -alL .config/pgcli/history
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lorentz lorentz 3580 jan 25 16:14 .config/pgcli/history

~/dotfiles $ \ls -ld ~/dotfiles
drwxrwxr-x 4 lorentz lorentz 4096 jan 22 21:16 /home/lorentz/dotfiles

~/dotfiles $ namei -lx .config/pgcli/history ~/.config/pgcli/history
f: .config/pgcli/history
drwxrwxr-x lorentz lorentz .config
drwxrwxr-x lorentz lorentz pgcli
-rw-rw-r-- lorentz lorentz history
f: /home/lorentz/.config/pgcli/history
Drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
drwxr-xr-x root    root    home
drwxr-x--- lorentz lorentz lorentz
drwx------ lorentz lorentz .config
lrwxrwxrwx lorentz lorentz pgcli -> ../dotfiles/.config/pgcli
drwxr-x--- lorentz lorentz   ..
drwxrwxr-x lorentz lorentz   dotfiles
drwxrwxr-x lorentz lorentz   .config
drwxrwxr-x lorentz lorentz   pgcli
-rw-rw-r-- lorentz lorentz history


~/dotfiles $ \stat ~/.config/pgcli/history
  File: /home/lorentz/.config/pgcli/history
  Size: 3580            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10305h/66309d   Inode: 574283      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ lorentz)   Gid: (30001/ lorentz)
Access: 2024-01-25 16:58:09.803772739 +0100
Modify: 2024-01-25 16:14:05.048623557 +0100
Change: 2024-01-25 16:14:05.048623557 +0100
 Birth: 2024-01-25 16:08:51.058707059 +0100

~/dotfiles $ \stat .config/pgcli/history
  File: .config/pgcli/history
  Size: 3580            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10305h/66309d   Inode: 574283      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ lorentz)   Gid: (30001/ lorentz)
Access: 2024-01-25 16:58:09.803772739 +0100
Modify: 2024-01-25 16:14:05.048623557 +0100
Change: 2024-01-25 16:14:05.048623557 +0100
 Birth: 2024-01-25 16:08:51.058707059 +0100

~/dotfiles $ mv .config/pgcli/history ~/.config/pgcli/history
mv: '.config/pgcli/history' and '/home/lorentz/.config/pgcli/history' are the same file
```

I am using

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Z shell
- GNU stow

Comment: `~` expands to your home and hence the prepended path `/home/lorentz` but `dotfiles` seems to be a symbolic link to your home and as a result, you are actually running `ls` from within your home when you run it from within `dotfiles` ... What's the output of `ls -l ~/dotfiles` ?

Comment: Mm, good idea. Doesn't look to be a symlink either though :( 
`\ls -ld ~/dotfiles` gives `drwxrwxr-x 4 lorentz lorentz 4096 jan 22 21:16 /home/lorentz/dotfiles`

Comment: Add the output of `namei -lx .config/pgcli/history ~/.config/pgcli/history` to the post, please.

Comment: They are the same file, no doubt given the same node number `Inode: 574283`  … So, `dotfiles` must resolve to your home and if it’s not a symlink then it could be a bind mount on top of your home or your filesystem space could be altered with userspace tools like Bubble Wrap or others or something else but it still resolves to your home nonetheless.

Comment: Ah right. It's the `~/.config/pgcli` directory that is a symlink... that solves it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a parent directory that was symlinked (`~/.config/pgcli`)

(Thanks to Raffa and muru)